# How to fix this bench vise that has a missing handle

Tags: workshop

I have a bench vise that is missing the piece that you grab onto to tighten it up.

Is it possible to replace this part?

[image]

Comment: Are you looking to buy a specific "vise handle" or what, because literally any long metal rod or bold that fits in the hole will work.

Comment: That's what I typically do when I use the vise, but I was wondering if I could get a proper replacement part.  I've tried to search for the vise online and can't find it.

Comment: I have never seen a replacement so I agree with Jphi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a long "grade 5" bolt, grind the head round and ease the edges a bit so to use it will be comfortable. Set it in place and run a stop nut on the other end and grind it in the same way. Do not get it too hot from grinding, it may melt the nylon part that keeps the nut in place.

There will be issues while doing this, but to grind the bolt first before placing it in the vise will at least make one part of the job easy to do. The other part, the nut, well....

You will only need to do it once.

Comment: You can also use a double Hex nut on the end and lock them together.

Comment: Yup "jam nuts" are what I call them, cranking down on 2 nuts, one tightening towards the other, so they lock in place on the threads

Answer (score 0):

Black or Galvanized iron pipe might fit & with caps screwed on the ends would give you all the function of the original, even put a hardened rod inside of it for extra strength.

Comment: I dont think Pipe would hold up as it used to be a solid steel shaft.

Comment: It doesn't need to be as strong as the original shaft, it just needs to ne stronger than you!